# Looping through recordset vb6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

So, I've done this a million different ways but this is bothering me a bit. I'm trying to loop through a recordset, identify a number and compare to the next record. If they match, I want to change matching value. It seems to work, somewhat, but then I get all records as "Matched".... saying that there is 'No matched record'. I'm sure it's something dumb I'm missing so if anyone could point out my flaw here, that would be awesome! As always, thanks in advance!!!

```
    con.Open _
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Books.mdb;" & _
"Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=4;"

rs1.Open "A", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTableDirect
rs2.Open "B", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTableDirect

rs1.MoveFirst
While Not rs1.EOF
    rs2.MoveFirst
    While Not rs2.EOF
         If rs1("ID").Value = rs2("ID").Value Then
         With rs2
            !Matching_Criteria = "Matched"
            .Update
            End With
         Else
             With rs2
            !Matching_Criteria = "UnMatched"
            .Update
            End With
         End If
        rs2.MoveNext
    Wend
rs1.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Your loop is overwriting previous results with each subsequent pass. You can do this with a simple update query that matches on the ID field - why are you looping over both recordsets?

Comment: [dbmitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419128/dbmitch) has got the point. Your `if` part is logically correct, but Your `else` part isn't. At every loop, it will overwrite all Your previous *matched* updates. Use that advice, and try to understand the code You are writing.

Comment: Thanks Dbmitch it seems that Matching is fine now but there is another problem that the process take much time , is there any way to reduce matching process period .

Comment: Looks like the looping issue is solved. As for the processing time, that would be an entirely different question, consider posting it separately.

Comment: Also you should read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions to understand better why I made my last comment.

Comment: Why would the process take long? Aren't you using an update query joined on the ID fields?

Answer (score -2):

1. Be sure that bot of tables are in monopoly access for you and/or use static rst (I don't remember clearly)
2. Populate both of rst's:

   .MoveLast
   .MoveFirst
   lCnt = .RecordsCount ' *(engine wan't to format it ...)*
3. Use `For i = 1 to lCnt` instead of `While ... Wend`
   .

Comment: Thanks for your reply currently two tables are placed in same database, but all records are shown as Matched but some of them are not matched i need another code which match each record in table A with table b and updated matching criteria with matching result

Comment: @AlaaHamdan The first: you use `.Update` wo `.Edit` and in second: try to use `.Field("ByName_As_String")` or `.Field("ByIndex_As_Long")` instead of exclamation `!`